# JCL : IF Statement with SET Statement

Tags: mainframe, jcl

I have set FLAG as 1 and I am execpting ARG value should be DEV only. But am getting as ARG= DEV + CLIENTID

```
000023 //         FLAG=1

000026 // IF (&FLAG=1) THEN        
000027 //SET1     SET ARG=DEV         
000028 // ELSE        
000029 //SET2     SET ARG=DEV+&CLIENT 
000030 // ENDIF
```

It mean JCL assign the value in RUNTIME (before checking the IF Condition).

Please help me to understand.

Thanks!
Bharathi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What @hogstrom said is correct. The JCL IF statement tests `Step Return codes` and not **Variable values**:

```
//IFBAD     IF  (ABEND | STEP1.RC > 8) THEN
```

Following on from what he said you can use a variable in an `include` statement

### Include With variable

```
//  INCLUDE MEMBER=OPT&FLAG
```

and setup members in the proclib

#### MEMBER=OPT1

```
  // SET ARG=DEV
```

#### MEMBER=OPT2

```
  // SET ARG=DEV+&CLIENT
```

You have to setup an include for **every** possible value of **&FLAG** and it is very long winded for one `SET`. It is more commonly used when you can set **lots** of variables like:

```
// INCLUDE MEMBER=ENV&ENV
```

where &ENV=`PROD` \ `TEST` etc

### Your case

Do not use flag, just set the variable:

```
// SET ARG=DEV
```

or

```
// SET ARG=DEV+&CLIENT
```

Answer (score 3):

There is some good information in the [JCL Manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.ieab600/iea3b6_Considerations_when_using_the_IF_THEN_ELSE_ENDIF_construct.htm) to understand the purpose of the IF/THEN/ELSE purpose.

Here are a few bullets from the manual:

> - The IF/THEN/ELSE/ENDIF statement construct does not conditionally    control the processing of JCL; rather, it conditionally controls the
>     execution of job steps.
> - The result of processing an IF/THEN/ELSE/ENDIF statement construct, once determined, remains unchanged regardless of the outcome from
>     running any remaining steps in a job. The system does not reexamine
>     the original condition at any later job step termination, either
>     normal or abnormal. See Example 9.
> - The system allocates all DD statements defined to a step if the execution time evaluation of the relational-expression determines
>     that a step is to be executed. All data sets defined on DD statements
>     in the job must be available at the time the job is selected for
>     execution.
> - You can nest IF/THEN/ELSE/ENDIF statement constructs up to a maximum of 15 levels. You can specify symbolic parameters on
>     IF/THEN/ELSE/ENDIF statements provided that they resolve to one of the
>     supported relational-expression keywords. Any other symbolic
>     parameters, even if accepted by the system, are not intended or
>     supported.

What your doing seems logical, but, its not the intended purpose of JCL SET and conditional logic.

In your case, the last SET executed is what is used and why your seeing the `DEV + CLIENTID`